# TypeError: Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null while running next.js

Tags: reactjs, next.js

While running

```
npm run dev
```

I suddenly start getting error without pretty much any change to the code of the project:

```
TypeError: Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null
    at Object.618 (/Users/EugeneBos/Websites/dotalaning/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/postcss-scss/scss-syntax.js:1:100)
    at __nccwpck_require__ (/Users/EugeneBos/Websites/dotalaning/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/postcss-scss/scss-syntax.js:1:11735)
    at Object.270 (/Users/EugeneBos/Websites/dotalaning/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/postcss-scss/scss-syntax.js:1:413)
    at __nccwpck_require__ (/Users/EugeneBos/Websites/dotalaning/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/postcss-scss/scss-syntax.js:1:11735)
    at Object.327 (/Users/EugeneBos/Websites/dotalaning/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/postcss-scss/scss-syntax.js:1:260)
    at __nccwpck_require__ (/Users/EugeneBos/Websites/dotalaning/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/postcss-scss/scss-syntax.js:1:11735)
    at Object.845 (/Users/EugeneBos/Websites/dotalaning/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/postcss-scss/scss-syntax.js:1:3733)
    at __nccwpck_require__ (/Users/EugeneBos/Websites/dotalaning/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/postcss-scss/scss-syntax.js:1:11735)
    at /Users/EugeneBos/Websites/dotalaning/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/postcss-scss/scss-syntax.js:1:11863
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/EugeneBos/Websites/dotalaning/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/postcss-scss/scss-syntax.js:1:11889)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1108:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1137:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:973:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:813:14)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:997:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:92:18)
```

Modifying the code of the app so it won't include any files or load anything still produces the same error.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ok, removing node_modules and installing everything again have helped.

```
rm -rf node_modules
npm install
```

Comment: I had a similar case. Pretty sure I accidentally ran the `yarn` command on my `npm` app.

Comment: @BradGreens hm I didn't know you cant use it both simultaneously, I have yarn as well there.

Answer (score 3):

Just update npm...

Sometimes it relates to the npm version, try to use the newest version of npm. It was happening to me on **v6.14**, once I updated npm to **v8.1** the issue was resolved.

Comment: Thanks! I was running Next.js with Node.js@20 on my local machine, but turns out that Vercel was running the pipeline with Node 18. Upgrading it to 20 solved it!

Answer (score 3):

Just adding another possible reason for this:

Node version might not be supported.

I just created a new nextjs project (currently version 13.4), and my node version was 16.5, but if using node 16, the minimum accepted was 16.14

Comment: This helped me! I updated from v16.0.0 to v20.3.0

Comment: I had to update my node apparently, which I did with homebrew. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I know there's nothing wrong with the good old `rm -rf` but **`npkill`** is quite a nice tool:

1. `npx npkill`
2. Remove the appropriate `node_modules` folder
3. `yarn` or `npm i`

Answer (score 0):

This might happen if you mix yarn with npm dependencies as well.
Try

1. rm-rf node_modules
2. npm install

This worked in my case

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to the party but still...

In my case I had a custom exception that extended `AssertionError`, imported from `assert` (coming from `node`).